# javascript inheritance challenges

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype, ecmascript-5

I'm learning how does the inheritance work in javascript. I followed [this example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript). Explaining the prototype chain. I created a little more elaborated example showing 3 levels `Person > Employee > Engineer`
The difference in my example is that to create the instance of `Employee` the argument is passed. However If I follow the mozilla example mentioned above I need to pass this into Child prototype:

```
 var Engineer.prototype = new(Employee);
```

where I do not pass any arguments.

After that when I print the `Engineer.prototype` content to console indeed I see the property "company" as "undefined".

```
Engineer prototype { _alive: true,
  _company: undefined,
  _title: null,
  constructor: [Function] }
Drew instance:  { _alive: true,
  _company: 'Apple',
  _title: null,
  _specialization: 'tester' }
```

I sure can live with this but it doesn't look to me very clean and neat.

The question here is what is the best practice? Shell I rather not to pass any arguments to constructors and create some init method and call it explicitly or shell I ignore the undefined properties in constructor?

here is the code from my example:

```
var Person = function(){
  this._alive = true;
};


var Employee = function(company){
  Person.call(this);
  this._company = company;
  this._title = null;
}

Person.prototype.die = function(){
  this._alive = false;
}


Employee.prototype = new Person();
Employee.prototype.constructor = Employee;

Employee.prototype.setTitle = function(newtitle){
  this._title = newtitle;
}
Employee.prototype.title = function(){
  return this._title;
}
Employee.prototype.company = function(){
  return this._company;
}

var Engineer = function(company, specialization){
  Employee.call(this,company);
  this._specialization = specialization;
}

Engineer.prototype = new(Employee);
Engineer.prototype.constructor = Engineer;

var drew = new(Engineer)('Apple','tester');

console.log('Engineer prototype', Engineer.prototype);    
console.log('Drew instance: ',drew);
```

Comment: Hm, I thought I had fixed that article once. See [related questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen-US%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FJavaScript%2FIntroduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript%22+is%3Aquestion) on how to do this correctly

Comment: @Bergi thanks for pointing me to good direction